# Auto Complete with json and bootstrap

Tags: php, json, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete

this is my code:

**class_search.php**

```
        case 'users':
            if(!empty($_REQUEST['user'])){                  
                if(strlen($_REQUEST['user']) >= 3){
                    $_REQUEST['user'] = $this->sanitize($_REQUEST['user'], 'string');
                    $stmt = $this->sql->prepare('SELECT
                                                        id,
                                                        nome,
                                                                                                                    url
                                                    FROM
                                                        animes
                                                    WHERE
                                                        nome LIKE ?

                                                    LIMIT 10');

                    $stmt->execute(array('%'.$_REQUEST['user'].'%'));
                    $this->queries++;
                    $c = 0;
                    if($admin){
                        $result['users'] = array();
                    }

                    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                            if($admin){
                                $result['users'][$c] = array('name'=>($prefix ? '[usr] ' : '').$row['nome'], 'id'=>$row['id']);
                                $c++;
                            }else{
                                $result[] = ($prefix ? '[usr] ' : '').$row['nome'];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
```

**general.js**

```
$('#top_search').typeahead({
    source: function(typeahead, query) {
        $.ajax({
            url: baseurl + "/ajax_calls.php",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                call: 'top_search',
                user: query
            },
            success: function(data) {
                typeahead.process(data);
            }
        });
    },
    onselect: function(obj) {
        location.href= baseurl + '/animes/'+obj;
    }
})
```

**ajax_calls.php**

```
        case 'top_search':
            $status = $site->process_autosearch('users');
            break

;
```

I am having problem with onselect, I need to select the row url in my MySQL and encode to json, because when I click in one result I am redirect to mysite.com/animes/name of anime/ (yes, with space) and I need to fix this.

Table animes in phpMyAdmin:
http://s18.postimage.org/3ulrcmss9/Animes_Table.jpg

Quickly video: http://www.screenr.com/plZ7

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).
In your class_search.php file, update this part:

```
if($admin){
    $result['users'][$c] = array('name'=>($prefix ? '[usr] ' : '').urlencode($row['nome']), 'id'=>$row['id']);
    $c++;
}else{
    $result[] = ($prefix ? '[usr] ' : '').urlencode($row['nome']);
}
```

And to make the names looks good in the searche auto-complete as well, you need to modify your jQuery as well, wrapping the [`decodeURIComponent()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp) function around the obj like so:

```
onselect: function(obj) {
    location.href= baseurl + '/animes/' + decodeURIComponent(obj);
}
```